# Sticky Footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

My HTML code:

```
<body id="main">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="name">
            <a href="index.html" title="Title" id="title">
            </a>

        </div>
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul id="items">
                ...
                ...    
                ...
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="container">

    </div>
    <div id="f">
        <footer>
            <p>footer footer footer footer</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="functions.js">
    </script>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#container {
    background-color: blue;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;

}
#f {
    clear: both;
    background-color: red;
    border-top-color: #d6d8d8;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    position:sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I want the footer to be at the bottom of the page, even if the container is empty (like in this example), however it's not working. I've tried to set container's minimum height as 100%, but when I open the page, it's height is 0 if there is no content

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `position:fixed;`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mqz7p4z7/)**

```
#f {
    clear: both;
    background-color: red;
    border-top-color: #d6d8d8;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    position:fixed;/**Change This***/
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it works, but only for pages that can fit into the window (you don't need to scroll down to view all the contents). Those pages that are long enough, the footer just floating at the bottom of the window, but not the page, so whenever I scroll down, it floats with me. How can I fix that now?

Answer (score 0):

change the css styles to:
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
and adjust height and width as per your requirement. You can set width:100%; also

Answer (score 0):

There you go, your (improved) code on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/erlingormar/Lprqwgpk/

Changed the positioning in the CSS selector `#f` from "sticky" to `fixed`.

```
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made sticky footer using this [tutorial](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/). I think it's easy and convenient to use.

**CSS CODE**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
#f {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```